# Kubernetes LoadBalancer is not responding? (Docker for Windows)

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

How can I setup the Kubernetes to work with LoadBalancer on Docker for Windows?

I have this very simple Kubernetes hello world:

```
kubectl run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=1 --port=80
kubectl expose deployment my-nginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
kubectl get svc
kubectl describe service my-nginx
curl -m 10 http://localhost/
curl -m 10 http://localhost:32026/
```

It does not work, the localhost is not responding. Output I get is:

```
deployment.apps "my-nginx" created
service "my-nginx" exposed
NAME       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
my-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.103.126.2   localhost     80:32026/TCP   0s
Name:                     my-nginx
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=my-nginx
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=my-nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.103.126.2
LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32026/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

the LoadBalancer seems to be there, in external IP but it does not work.

I have tested that I can get inside the pod with `kubectl exec pod-name -it -- bash` and I can see that nginx is running in the pod. However it's not accessible from Windows.

I have also tested that connection with Docker images *does work* just fine:

```
docker run -dit --rm --name nginx -p 80:80 nginx
curl -m 10 http://localhost/
docker stop nginx
```

This works.

Connection to LoadBalancer in Kubernetes is somehow broken, does it work for others, and any ways to fix this?

Docker for Windows, 
Version 2.0.0.3 (31259), 
Channel: stable,
Build: 8858db3

Comment: Can you please post the output of `kubectl describe service my-nginx`? It will helpful in debugging.

Comment: @NavneetNandanJha I've edited, and added that also.

Comment: @Ciantic have you get it to work because i am facing the same issue and need help

Comment: @JayD no I have not, I think not many still use Kubernetes with Docker for Windows. It works with minikube of course, but that is waste of resources because Docker for Windows already has the environment for the Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

The server is listening on the port 32270, try localhost:32270

Comment: I think it's not, but I tried also that: `my-nginx     LoadBalancer   10.101.174.105   localhost     80:32155/TCP   13h` and then http://localhost:32155 but it does not respond either.

Comment: I suppose you're using minikube, to access the service try : `minikube service my-nginx`, to get the url try : `minikube service my-nginx --url`

Comment: I use Docker for Windows, it should support LoadBalancer, I need someone who also uses it to try.

Comment: Yes, but you have a Kubernetes cluster. Do you deploy it using minikube ? I know you run Docker on Windows, but here you did two different things; you run nginx inside a container using Docker and you can reach it via localhost: OK.
The other thing, you run a nginx inside a container inside a pod in a Kubernetes cluster, to access the server you used a LoadBalancer. I said, if you use minikube, try the above commands.

Comment: I don't use Minikube, it's another tool. Docker for Windows has a local cluster builtin for Kubernetes, which should support LoadBalancer without anything else according to maintainers: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1681#issuecomment-467920996